# Reading from multiline variable in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a variable which contains a multi-line string. I need to read the first two lines and do some processing based on their values.
How can I do this ?

A sample value inside my variable is

```
 Description: some value
 Entity: Some value
 Fixed
```

I need to get the first two lines (Description and Entity) as different variables.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "$var"
Description: some value
Entity: Some value
Fixed

$ var2=$(sed -n 1p <<< "$var")

$ var3=$(sed -n 2p <<< "$var")

$ echo $var2
Description: some value

$ echo $var3
Entity: Some value
```

If you only want the values:

```
$ var2=$(sed -n '1s/.*: //p' <<< "$var")

$ var3=$(sed -n '2s/.*: //p' <<< "$var")

$ echo $var2
some value

$ echo $var3
Some value
```

Same thing with `grep`:

```
$ var2=$(grep Description <<< "$var")

$ var3=$(grep Entity <<< "$var")

$ echo $var2
Description: some value

$ echo $var3
Entity: Some value
```

Only values:

```
$ var2=$(grep -Po "Description: \K.*" <<< "$var")

$ var3=$(grep -Po "Entity: \K.*" <<< "$var")

$ echo $var2
some value

$ echo $var3
Some value
```

Answer (score 2):

On example:

```
$ echo "$MYVAR"
Description: some value
Entity: Some value
Fixed

$ VAR1=$(echo "$MYVAR" | sed -n 1p)

$ VAR2=$(echo "$MYVAR" | sed -n 2p)
```

`VAR1` and `VAR2` now contain first and second line of `MYVAR`, respectively:

```
$ echo $VAR1
Description: some value

$ echo $VAR2
Entity: Some value
```